# C++ Initializer List with auto_ptr

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

How come this compiles and works:

```
class MyObject {
public:
  MyObject() {}
};

struct ItemGood {
  int Number;
  MyObject *Object;

  ItemGood(int Number, MyObject *Object) {
    this->Number = Number;
    this->Object = Object;
  }
};

const ItemGood ItemGoodList[] =
{
  { 0, new MyObject() },
  { 1, new MyObject() }
};
```

And this does not compile at all:

```
class MyObject {
public:
  MyObject() {}
};

struct ItemBad {
  int Number;
  std::auto_ptr<MyObject> AutoObject;

  ItemBad(int Number, MyObject *Object) {
    this->Number = Number;
    AutoObject = std::auto_ptr<MyObject>(Object);
  }
};

const ItemBad ItemBadList[] =
{
  { 0, new MyObject() },
  { 1, new MyObject() }
};
```

The error the compiler spits out is:

> no matching function for call to 'ItemBad::ItemBad(ItemBad)

I do not understand why something is trying to call that constructor, I don't understand what is actually happening in this initializer list.

Comment: Which compiler? Compiles fine for me (gcc 4.6.1).

Comment: mingw-32 4.4, hmm I wonder why that happens

Comment: gcc 4.5.2 does not compile, gives the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `std::auto_ptr` does not have a proper copy constructor, which means your class does not have a proper copy constructor, which means that it cannot be constructed from a temporary- which is what you're trying to do.

Just junk `auto_ptr` and move to `unique_ptr`.

Comment: Yes that makes a lot of sense, will have to wait for C++11 :-(

Comment: @oggmonster What do you mean wait? C++11 is already here. Just use the flag `-std=c++0x` when you compile you program.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
ItemBad(int Number, MyObject *Object) : Number(Number), AutoObject(Object) 
{}
```

Seems like `std::auto_ptr` does not have copy-constructor on your platform, so it must be initialized before contructor's body.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, you should avoid using initialization lists like this:

```
{ 0, new MyObject() }
```

Instead, use constructor:

```
ItemBad(0, new MyObject())
```

For instance, MSVC compiler generates error for your "good" variant as well as for "bad" one: as soon as your class has a ctor, you must use it, not initialization lists.

Answer (score 0):

Every `{ 0, new MyObject() }` expression is replaced with a constructor call `ItemGood(int Number, MyObject *Object)`, so the compilers makes something like this:

```
const ItemGood ItemGoodList[] =
{
  ItemGood(0, new MyObject()), // temporal 'ItemGood' 1 (const &)
  ItemGood(1, new MyObject())  // temporal 'ItemGood' 2 (const &)
};
```

Then the compiler-generated copy costructor for `ItemGood` is invoked to fill the array slot for every `ItemGood`, no problems here

The `ItemBad` class declaration contains the member variable `std::auto_ptr<MyObject> AutoObject` and as pointed in another answers, `std::auto_ptr` does not have copy-constructor, so the compiler can't create its *compiler-generated* copy costructor for `ItemBad`. When the previous  logic is applied, we get the same expression replacement as with `ItemGood`

```
const ItemBad ItemGoodList[] =
{
  ItemBad(0, new MyObject()), // temporal 'ItemBad' 1 (const &)
  ItemBad(1, new MyObject())  // temporal 'ItemBad' 2 (const &)
};
```

But here we don't have copy-constructor, so the error you reported occurs, using initialization list in the `ItemBad` constructor won't solve the problem and deleting the `MyObject` assignation won't solve the problem either

```
ItemBad(int Number, MyObject *Object) {
   this->Number = Number;
   // AutoObject = std::unique_ptr<MyObject>(Object);  This comment doesn't solve the problem
}
```

Change to `unique_ptr` as stated before, or use boost [shared_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm)